# C# linq merge two collections by condition with "leading" collection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to find a solution to an actually not so complicated problem but I didn't find it - maybe I've got the wrong keywords to look for, maybe I'm to tired to understand the docs correctly - whatever it is ... I'm stuck.

I have two collections of db-entities and I want to merge them by condition. If two items in both collections match condition, I want to take the one from `myCollection`. Every other item should be added to `mergeCollection`. I've wrote a cumbersome foreach but there must be a better solution. Would be pretty happy if someone can tell me how to solve this in a short and elegant way.

The type doesn't really matter, could be any object. Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int AnotherValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is my foreach:

```
void Merge(List<MyClass> myCollection)
{
    var mergeCollection = await dbContext.MyClass.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var updatedItem in myCollection)
    {
        if (updatedItem.SomeValue == default && updatedItem.AnotherValue == default)
            mergeCollection.Add(updatedItem);
        else
        {
            var oldItem = mergeCollection.First(e => e.Id == updatedItem.Id);
            mergeCollection.Remove(oldItem);
            mergeCollection.Add(updatedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if SomeValue and AnotherValue have the default value, you don't want to remove the item from DB-list, even if the Id equals the myCollection-item, which means you can have duplicate Id's afterwards? Anyway, your loop is fine for what you are doing: modifying collections.

Comment: Yes. This is part of an upsert routine - if someValue and anotherValue are in default state, myClass is in insert-state. All other objects were updated but the update was not applied to the database. Anyway - a duplicate Id should not occur in mergeCollection...

Comment: Then you can simplify the logic and just rely on the Id-Check. You are adding all anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to modify collections, a loop is perfect for this. LINQ is a "tool" to query collections, not to modify them. So in my opionion you are asking for the wrong tool and you're using already the right one. However, maybe you find this approach more readable (i prefer yours):

```
void Merge(List<MyClass> myCollection)
{
    HashSet<Guid> myIds = myCollection.Select(i => i.Id).ToHashSet();
    List<MyClass> mergeCollection = await dbContext.MyClass.Where(i => !myIds.Contains(i.Id)).ToListAsync();
    mergeCollection.RemoveAll(i => myCollection
        .Any(i2 => i.Id == i2.Id && (i2.SomeValue != default || i2.AnotherValue != default)));
    mergeCollection.AddRange(myCollection);
}
```

This might be more efficient since i can use `List<T>.AddRange(otherList)`.

Since you've clarified that those items which are in "default-state" don't have the same ID's than those in `mergeCollection`, you can make it even more efficient:

```
void Merge(List<MyClass> myCollection)
{
   HashSet<Guid> myIds = myCollection.Select(i => i.Id).ToHashSet();
   List<MyClass> mergeCollection = await dbContext.MyClass
      .Where(i => !myIds.Contains(i.Id))
      .ToListAsync();
   mergeCollection.AddRange(myCollection);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a try tonight. Thanks for clarifying linq-scope :)

Comment: @Joshit: added a simpler and more efficient approach, since according to your comment it seems that the default check is unnecessary. Here you don't load the entities from DB which are part of your myCollection.